# How to configure debug mode with PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm configured debug mode like following with `PhpStorm` and `php.ini` .

1. PHP Buillt-in Web Server Settings

```
 HOST: localhost 
 PORT: 9000
 Document root: [Project root path]
 Interpreter options: artisan serve
```

2. /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini

```
    [xdebug]
    zend_extension=xdebug.so
    #zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.16/pecl/20180731/xdebug.so"
    xdebug.remote_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_port="9000"
```

IF I execute from Run button with PhpStorm, following messages come up at first page.

[image]

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.16/bin/php -S localhost:9000 
-t /Users/xxxx/Works/Projects/sample_server artisan serve
[Tue Mar 31 23:37:15 2020] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: argv in /Users/xxx/Works/Projects/sample_server/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 49
```

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.3.16 (cli) (built: Mar 19 2020 11:20:31) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.16, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.16, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

When I run `php artisan serve` from command line console, it works well.
What else do I need to do?
Please give me advice.

Comment: Check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ **P.S.** `xdebug.remote_port="8000"` -- this is wrong -- it has to be a Xdebug port on which PhpStorm listens and not web server port. Xdebug is the one that connects to IDE and not other way around -- see xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: *"IF I execute from Run button with PhpStorm, following messages come up at first page."* What file exactly do you execute? Screenshots are very welcome in such cases.

Comment: I changed the port number, but it dose not work. I expect laravel first welcome page comes up.

Comment: I added Error stack trace.

Comment: *"...-S localhost:9000..."* No, you misunderstood it completely. Better describe what are you trying to do and provide screenshots.

Comment: Now my all settings are port 9000. Sorry for mixed up.

Comment: I would like to execute debug at port 9000. And I would like to debug with PhpStorm.

Comment: I say: 1) just run `php artisan serve` in console as you would normally do 2) then use "Zero config" approach to execute and debug your web pages when you control what to debug via Xdebug browser extension. Just make sure that "phone handle" icon is enabled during that time (so IDE is listening for incoming debug connections) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html . Grab some Larvel + PhpStorm tutorial and follow it. To start with: https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/19

Comment: Is it problem if 1 `php artisan serve` port is 8000, but the others port settings are 9000?

Comment: Web server port should be DIFFERENT to Xdebug port -- as they used for completely different purposes. With web server, you (browser) connect to server, with Xdebug it's other way around -- Xdebug connects to IDE. If you use the same port for both .. then Xdebug will simply be trying to connect to web server instead of IDE. Just use defaults (well, can use 9001 instead of 9000 for Xdebug (in both PhpStorm and php.ini) and follow some guide (start with that Laracast episode etc).

Comment: Now I understand. The settings were not wrong. Thank you.