# How to configure PHP Build-in Web Server with PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm from following question.

[How to configure debug mode with PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60952181/how-to-configure-debug-mode-with-phpstorm)

However my question has been changed.

When I tried set up `RUN` `php artisan serve` from `RUN` button up on PhpStorm menu.
Error page is always comes up as same as previous question.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.16/bin/php -S localhost:8000 -t /xxxx/Projects/juno_server artisan serve
[Wed Apr  1 14:17:52 2020] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: argv in /xxxx/Projects/juno_server/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 49
[Wed Apr  1 14:17:52 2020] PHP Stack trace:
[Wed Apr  1 14:17:52 2020] PHP   1. {main}() /xxxx/Projects/juno_server/artisan:0
[Wed Apr  1 14:17:52 2020] PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->__construct() /xxxx/Projects/juno_server/artisan:36
[Wed Apr  1 14:17:52 2020] PHP Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /xxxx/Projects/juno_server/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 53
[Wed Apr  1 14:17:52 2020] PHP Stack trace:
[Wed Apr  1 14:17:52 2020] PHP   1. {main}() /xxxx/Projects/juno_server/artisan:0
[Wed Apr  1 14:17:52 2020] PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->__construct() /xxxx/Projects/juno_server/artisan:36
[Wed Apr  1 14:17:52 2020] PHP   3. array_shift() /xxxx/Projects/juno_server/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:53
```

[image]
What is wrong?

Comment: You don't want to use the built-in web server. Running `artisan serve` just requires the PHP binary

Comment: Why not?  Don't you recommend use tools?

Comment: Please see the post linked at the top of your question. Hopefully it will make sense then.